PATH variable inconsistency when using either remote desktop or ssh on a remote Windows system
I have a virtual Windows 10 machine which is accessible on our company network via either remote desktop or ssh.
If I

log in via remote desktop,
open a command prompt and
type path

I get a path equivalent to the PATH variable I set using the Windows system settings.
In contrast, if I

open an ssh connection (using the same user account)
type path

some paths are missing.
Why do I get two different results?
